# Non-Italian European mafias in USA?

Tags: united-states, italian, organised-crime

Italian mafias are a well-known example of an ethnic-based mafia in USA but are there other examples of European mafias based in ethnicity in USA?

I'm especially interested in North European examples, e.g., a German mafia or Prussian mafia or similar.

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, @d-b! What has your research shown you so far?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].
Thanks!

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace i think this Q is simply funny and intriguing. Isn't this for you :)?

Comment: As there is no German or Prussian Mafia in Germany (or former Prussia) you would be hard pressed to find such structures imported into the US.

Comment: @nvoigt Makes some sense!

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Are 'list' questions OK on this SE?

Comment: List questions are discouraged. There is no way to select an authoritative answer.

Comment: This question would probably be improved by precising which time-frame the OP is interested in (for instance, first half of 20th century).

Answer (score 32):

Probably the best-known non-Italian '*ethnic-based mafia*' that operated in the USA was the [Unione Corse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unione_Corse).

This group were not North-European, but were part of the [Corsican Mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corsican_mafia) and maintained the so-called [French Connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Connection) monopoly, controlling the import of Heroin, from French Indo-China, through France (and Canada) into the United States from the 1930s until the late 1970s.

---

The Irish organised crime groups that operated from the nineteenth century onwards are another well known group that might be classified as an '*ethnic-based mafia*'.  Sometimes collectively known as the "[Irish Mob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Mob)", this group actually originated in the Irish street gangs in the United States.

Those gangs were made famous (or, perhaps more accurately, infamous) by Herbert Asbury's 1928 book [The Gangs of New York](https://archive.org/details/GangsOfNewYork_201811), which was loosely adapted into Martin Scorsese's 2002 film of the same name. As a group whose members are linked to a North-European country, this might meet your requirements.

In this case, the Irish Mob appears to have originated in the US in the nineteenth century and then expanded back into Ireland at some point in the 1960s.  This growth of organised crime in Ireland was the subject of the 3-part documentary series [Bad Fellas](https://web.archive.org/web/20170609192549/http://www.rte.ie/tv/programmes/bad_fellas.html) on RTÉ Television.

---

Although operating on a smaller scale, the so-called "[Polish Mob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish-American_organized_crime)" are another North-European '*ethnic-based mafia*'.

Some well-known elements include the [Saltis-McErlane Gang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Saltis) in Chicago, the Kielbasa Posse in Philadelphia, the Greenpoint Crew from Brooklyn, the [Flats Mob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Filkowski) in Cleveland, and the The [Flathead gang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flathead_gang) in Detroit.

---

As for your specific question about German or Prussian mafias operating in the United states, I have to say that I haven't found any references to a significant 'German mafia' or 'Prussian mafia' operating in the United States.

I did find [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/7ymvtg/was_there_such_as_thing_as_a_german_mob_in_the/) that also seems to suggest that, while it seems likely that there were some German criminal groups active in the US, they didn't operate on the same scale as some other groups:

> I've researched and written about the early years of the Mafia in the US, and looked at Jewish and Irish organised crime in New York as well, I have never come across any references to a German equivalent. This is not to say it never occurred – and in fact, given that at least 6 million German emigrated to the US during the 19th and early 20th centuries, I'd be very surprised if it never did – but certainly Germans were not as prominent as other ethnic groups in organised crime.

---

Finally, it is worth noting that Wikipedia maintains a list of '"Criminal enterprises, gangs and syndicates", which includes a (presumably not exhaustive) list of [gangs operating in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_criminal_enterprises,_gangs_and_syndicates#United_States).

Included in this list you will also find the [Jewish-American organised-crime groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish-American_organized_crime) that were active in the United States in the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries, and which are not infrequently referred to as the ' Jewish Mafia' in the media and popular culture.  Some members of these groups did have German ancestry.

Comment: Any Nordic or Scandinavian mafias?

Comment: @d-b None that I could find with any significant presence in the US. (Unless you count the Norse expeditions by Leif Erikson _et. al_. to Vinland,  c1000 CE)

Comment: Corsica is sort of Italian.

Comment: @gerrit You mean apart from the fact that it is French?

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yes, apart from the fact that it is ruled by France.  [Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corsican_language) and culture are closer to Italian than to French.  The same way in which Südtirol is sort of Austrian.  National borders are not always aligned with cultural borders.

Comment: @gerrit According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corsican_nationalism?wprov=sfla1) it is more "sort of French". Are you thinking of Sicily?

Comment: @TripeHound No, I'm definitely thinking of Corsica, which has long had an independence movement, as well as [Italian irridentism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_irredentism_in_Corsica), has been French for less than 300 years, and where Italian was the main public language until the 19th century.  The [place names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communes_of_the_Haute-Corse_department) are almost all essentially Italian as well including the name Corsica itself.

Comment: @gerrit Italian irredentism was largely promoted by Italy & was effectively snuffed out by WW2. I know a number of Corsicans who all identify as _Corsican_ First and _French_ second (and expressly _not_ Italian). However, what is important in this context is that the Unione Corse evolved and operated predominantly in Corsica & Marseilles, and that the Corsican Mafia is considered to be part of the '[French mob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milieu_(organized_crime_in_France))', rather than their Italian counterparts.

Comment: @gerrit Corsica is sort of Italian in the way that Ireland is sort of English.

Comment: _[Corsica independence intensifies]_

Comment: I would say the Irish Mob is much more well-known than the Unione Corsica.

Comment: @AzorAhai Perhaps.  Although there is a fairly well-known 1971 movie about the [French Connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_French_Connection_(film)) which helped bring their activities to the attention of a wider audience.

Comment: @gerrit: The most well known corsican is Napoleone di Buonaparte, known by most as Napoleon (the well-known Emperor of France)

Comment: The _Unione Corse_ features in Frederick Forsyth's novel, _The Day of the Jackal_. Many of its members supported the OAS (_Secret Army Organisation_) in its plotting against De Gaulle.

Answer (score 15):

> **Question:**
>   Non Italian European organized crime groups in the United States.

Ethnic Organized Crime groups which meet the criteria of your question operating in the United States are.

- **[69th St Gang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Rosen_(mobster))** Philadelphia Jewish Gang
- **[Cape Verdean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Verdean_organized_crime)** - French, Netherlands, Portugal, and New England
- **[The Combined (Group)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Combined_(Group))** - Jewish Italian Irish Organized Crime precursor to the Cosa Nostra
- **[The Irish Mob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Mob)**
- **[The Israeli Mob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_mafia)** - Jewish
- **[Lenox Avenue Gang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenox_Avenue_Gang)** - Jewish
- **[Purple Gang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Purple_Gang)** - predominantly Jewish members
- **[Russian Mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_mafia)** - Russian

  - **[Solomon Crime Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Solomon_(racketeer))** - Jewish Russian
- **[Sagansky Organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Sagansky)** - Jewish
- **[Philadelphia Greek Mob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velentzas_crime_family)**
- **[Velentzas Crime Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Solomon_(racketeer))** - Greek

Comment: The [Hell's Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hells_Angels) likely count too, as they generally don't allow non-white (eg: European-descended) members.

Comment: @T.E.D. One could probable list more than 20 biker gangs like that as well as various Arian Groups ,

Comment: But no "Prussian Mafia"? // Your distinction between Sicilian and Italian Mafia might benefit from clarification, as currently I do not understand what that sentence should convey.

Comment: @LangLangC The difference between Sicily and Italy is greater than the difference between Germany and Austria. Sicilians have a different language, complexion, and culture. Particularly when dealing Pre-Italian Unification or the first few generations afterwards, the two are quite different.

Comment: @Lan Maybe so.  But both 'regions' (and their people) are now part of the same state and that difference is just not seen by that many people. Even you had felt the need to explain it in comments… &still: was/is the Italian Mafia non-existent, not as well organised, grown out of Sicily? What is 'oddly' about it?

Comment: @LangLangC. I think I'm wrong here,  [Frank Costello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Costello) who took over the Luchese family when Lucky Luciano was placed in prison wasn't Sicilian,  but Italian.   So I think while it started out as Sicilian, by WWII they were accepting Italians not just as soldiers but as heads of one of the five families,

Comment: Thx for writing so much interesting stuff in comments. But wouldn't it benefit the universal understanding of the answer to at least write "Oddly enough the *American 'Mafia'*" or sth to that effect. Now 'Mafia' is used for a wide range of groups and in the beginning *only* the Sicilian original was called that way?

Comment: @LangLangC,  Took out the comment.  I think you were more right than I was.  Thank you.

Comment: Good answer. How many Jewish mobs there were.....

Comment: @KentaroTomono A number of high-ranking members of other ethnic mobs were Jewish, as well.

Comment: Is your list exhaustive ? It also is formulated in a bigotted structure (listing all Jewish gangs induce a representative bias). Why not list all Irish and Polish and Mediterranean organisations ?

Comment: not sure if combined group should count with the requested criterea?  also, according to wiki, the lennox avenue gang included  Francesco Cirofisi, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Cirofici) who is Italian?

Comment: @T.E.D. : The question asked about Mafia-syle criminal enterprises, which have their main purpose of making money from smuggling and other types of illegal business activities. Ideological groups, merely because they have ideologies you don't agree with (even if some of their members sometimes committed violent crimes) shouldn't count.

Comment: @vsz - Suggest you click the link I provided. "Numerous police and international intelligence agencies classify the Hells Angels as one of the "big four" motorcycle gangs, along with the Pagans, Outlaws, and Bandidos, and contend that members carry out widespread violent crime and organized crime, including drug dealing, trafficking in stolen goods, and extortion, and are involved in prostitution."

Comment: @T.E.D. : so, if some members of stackoverflow are involved in violent crime and drugs, does it makes stackoverflow a Mafia-style enterprise? I admit, that some motorcycle gangs likely have higher percentages of their membership doing so than this community, but they are still primarily a motorcycle gang, while the members of a Mafia-style enterprise congregate primarily to make money.

Comment: @vsz - If it organizes them to commit those acts, yes. But that's probably a determination best left to enforcement authorities who are experts in that kind of thing, like the FBI.

Answer (score 2):

Ethnic organised crime is almost always formed when there is an emigration from a poor country into an urbanised area in another country. Especially where the emigrants form a permanent lower class, or is discriminated against for their ethnicity. Before the wave of immigrants from Italy to the US there was a wave of immigrants from Scandinavia (mostly Sweden) and there was Scandinavian mafias. Working in the docks was a common line of work and they banded together as the spoke little English so they soon came to control the smuggling. Prostitution was also common (and the rumours about "Swedish sin" still sticks).

One example of a Swedish mafia boss in the US is [Frederick Lundin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Lundin) who actually built up the crime syndicate later taken over by the more famous Al Capone.
An example of a prohibition era Swedish mobster is [Simon Lundberg](https://www.minnenasjournal.nu/simon-lundberg-svensk-gangster-i-forbudstidens-usa/) who ran the speakeasy N.N. Club.

Answer (score -2):

All current ones.

As these mafias/organized crimes groups are based in the USA, with persons naturalized or born in the USA, all of the involved persons are Americans.

Their ancestry or place of birth does not matter.

Comment: Pretty sure that the organized crime along the Mexican border is dominated by Mexicans.

Comment: @Mark You might be surprised how MS 13 is contesting some of those assumptions.

Comment: If ancestry is relevant in membership being granted or denied, how is that irrelevant in defining a gang?